# NLP (topic modeling) with PLSA

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling

Im trying to understand **PLSA** (probabilistic latent semantic analysis), to do text modeling (NLP), the problem in every article i red, it's only maths (probabilities), without any semi-algorithme or anything to help you understand that, is there any link where i can understand PLSA please ?

Answer (score 0):

The P in PLSA stands for probablistic and hence I am afraid you may not find any article that does not talk about these. The model itself is a probablistic model and some knowledge of joints, conditionals, independence etc are expected. I would recommend https://medium.com/nanonets/topic-modeling-with-lsa-psla-lda-and-lda2vec-555ff65b0b05 which I found to be the best online resource. There is a bit of Math but most of it is explained well. About PLSA algorithm - I am not sure. It is not used that often and one almost always prefers LDA. I could find a GitHub implementation of solving PLSA using EM here: https://github.com/laserwave/plsa.